# SQL Server : How to find the difference between a given date and next relative day?

Tags: sql-server

how can I get the date difference (in days) between a starting date `2016-07-01` (1st July, it is a friday) and next tuesday?

Thanks you!

Comment: you have to be more specific. Your description is a rather vague. Please post example and expected result

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  How about this?

```
select (case when datename(dow, date) = 'Monday' then 1
             when datename(dow, date) = 'Tuesday' then 7
             when datename(dow, date) = 'Wednesday' then 6
             when datename(dow, date) = 'Thursday' then 5
             when datename(dow, date) = 'Friday' then 4
             when datename(dow, date) = 'Saturday' then 3
             when datename(dow, date) = 'Sunday' then 2
        end)
```

Comment: can you please explain what are the numbers for?

Comment: @wesley . . . "how can I get the date difference (in days)".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Answer (score 0):

How about a recursive cte?

```
;with cte as
(SELECT 0 as d
, DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, 0, CONVERT(date, '20160701'))) dname
union all
select d + 1
, DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day, d + 1, CONVERT(date, '20160701'))) dname
from cte
where d < 6
)
select d as NumberOfDaysUntil
, dname
from cte
where dname = 'Tuesday'
```

Starting from current day, it gets the weekdays for a week and finds the first name match. If you want to skip date you are starting from, change 0 to 1 and `< 6` to `< 7`